# Sorting a FASTA sequence file according to species names using sed

Tags: sed, sort, bioinformatics

I have a FASTA file of 536 DNA sequences containing multiple species, but it is not necessarily in order according to species name.

My headers with the sequences look like

```
>COLFG678-14|MZ630002|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P
AATC
>INRMA1514-14|NA|Agabus|thomsoni|ABZ7453|COI-5P
ATTT
>CONOR053-14|NA|Agabus|sturmii|AAJ1337|COI-5P
ACAA
>COLFG676-14|MZ631238|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P
AATG
```

The sequences contain the characters {A, C, G, T} and are usually hundreds of characters in length.

I need all species names to occur together in my FASTA file, as well as all other species in my dataset.

Here, a "species" refers to the species name in the FASTA header at the third and fourth delimited spots in the header. So, for the first header, `">COLFG678-14|MZ630002|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P"`, the species name is *Agabus adpressus*.

The output I need should be

```
>COLFG676-14|MZ631238|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P
AATG
>COLFG678-14|MZ630002|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P
AATC
>CONOR053-14|NA|Agabus|sturmii|AAJ1337|COI-5P
ACAA
>INRMA1514-14|NA|Agabus|thomsoni|ABZ7453|COI-5P
ATTT
```

Basically, I just need to sort by species name, so that all species with the same name occur together. Note I could easily have

```
>COLFG678-14|MZ630002|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P
AATC
>COLFG676-14|MZ631238|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P
AATG
>CONOR053-14|NA|Agabus|sturmii|AAJ1337|COI-5P
ACAA
>INRMA1514-14|NA|Agabus|thomsoni|ABZ7453|COI-5P
ATTT
```

where the order of the first two headers is swapped. What matters is that headers with the species name still occur together.

I think the easiest way to do this is by using `sed` (I'm running on a Mac Pro).

I know I should have something like

```
sed -i.bak ... file.fas // sort sequences and create a backup copy
```

but I'm not sure what `...` should be as I am new with regular expressions. I think I need to split at the third and fourth delimiters `|`, i.e. `|Agabus|adpressus|`, but I am not sure how to best indicate this.

Comment: Also, please show your current attempt. As much as we love to help, we're not a free code writing service for geneticists. We could make a ton of money that way, though.

Comment: "_I need all Agabus adpressus sequences_" - does this mean "_I need all lines containing the phrase 'Agabus adpressus'_"? Phrase your requirement in computational terms and you'll get a much better response. Most of us here are not bioinformatics people

Comment: As a hint, "_I have a FASTA file of 536 sequences containing multiple species_" means to me something along the lines of "_I have a file that's {something to do with bioinformatics} of 536 {somethings} containing multiple {otherthings}_".

Comment: "_My headers look like […]_" - does this mean you have multiple headers in this "FASTA" file? How do we differentiate a header from whatever else is in the file?

Comment: If your fasta file also contains sequence data, then please include this in the example (also, don't include characters that are not part of the data, like double quotes). People here do not know what fasta files usually look like. For a more bioinformatic-savvy crowd, try the Bioinformatics site at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to sort the lines by fields of 3 and 4. Fields separated by |

```
$ sed 'N;s/\n/#/g' infile | sort -t '|' -k3,4 | tr '#' '\n'

>COLFG676-14|MZ631238|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P
AATG
>COLFG678-14|MZ630002|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P
AATC
>CONOR053-14|NA|Agabus|sturmii|AAJ1337|COI-5P
ACAA
>INRMA1514-14|NA|Agabus|thomsoni|ABZ7453|COI-5P
ATTT
```

Comment: In addition to headers, my FASTA file contains DNA sequences (one sequence for each header). Your implementation works, but separates the sequences from the headers. I need the sequences to also correspond with the headers. I will modify my question to make things clearer.

Comment: @compbiostats, code amended to suit your updated request

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -t'|' -k3 -k4 fasta.txt
```

Output:

```
">COLFG678-14|MZ630002|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P"
">COLFG678-14|MZ630002|Agabus|adpressus|AEC6988|COI-5P"
">CONOR053-14|NA|Agabus|sturmii|AAJ1337|COI-5P"
">INRMA1514-14|NA|Agabus|thomsoni|ABZ7453|COI-5P"
```

`-t'|'` use vertical dash as the field separator.

`-k3 -k4` sort by 3rd and 4th fields.